# sql sum and excel sum difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

When I use TSQL [2005] SUM() function on these numbers:

```
4562500,
6387500,
2860000,
1825000,
348000,
2737500,
3102500,
6570000,
2007500,
2007500,
4380000,
9125000,
936000,
936000,
1040000,
264000,
240000,
1200000,
4562500,
4.80E+08,
4000000,
1176000,
660000,
1104000,
1404000,
1341600,
1534000,
1466400,
6684000,
3000000,
3600000,
5.14E+09,
0,
2.60E+07,
4197500,
2736000,
3084000,
2916000,
2640000,
480000,
1200000,
1.80E+08,
6000000,
840000,
9600000,
3744000,
4200000,
3060000,
7230000,
1.24E+07,
600000,
150000,
400000,
2100000
```

It gives me `5978168776`.

while same calculation in MS Excel 2007 gives `5978169000`.

When I calculated the result manually I got `5978169000` same as Excel.

Anyone knows why does SQL Server is functioning this way?
thanks

Comment: It may be the approximation of numbers like `1.24E+07` done differently by the two systems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @user2989408 `1.24E+07` in an int not a float. `1.24E+07 = 12400000`

Comment: Here's the result I got: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/224bb/1

Comment: @Jhon Can you remove the answer from your question text and make it a real answer. You can then marked it as the correct answer after (IIRC) 2 days.

Comment: It is impossible -even for SQL-Server- to come up with a value of `5978168776` when none of the values is ` mod 100 != 0`. So I guess there is something weird/wrong with either your observation or the sample data you posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jan Doggen

Ok- I did it!
Thank you all so much!

I created a table from `SUM()` argument values and then applied `SUM()` to these values:
my `SUM` statement:
`SELECT SUM(GrsPrice) From tblItem`

That resulted in `5978168776` .

`tblItem` schema:

```
USE [BudgetDb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblItem](
[ItemCode] [varchar](4) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL
[GrsPrice] [real] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

SQL Server type for `SUM()` values is `real` instead of `bigint` and this is problem origin.

@w0lf even in SQL Server 2008 result is `5974638744` when value type is `real`